# How can I better animate a modal using CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to use transitions to change the way a modal I created is shown on the screen. I need the modal to slide in from the left but the code doesn't seem to work. The app is in React.

The JSX code

```
const Modal = (props)=>{
  let ModalClasses = [Styles.Modal];
  if(props.show){
    ModalClasses = [Styles.Modal, Styles.Open]
  }
  return(
    <div className={ModalClasses.join(' ')}>
        <div className={Styles.ModalNav} onClick={props.clicked}>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

CSS

```
.Modal{
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 500ms ease-out;
}
.Modal.Open{
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.ModalNav div{
  height: 3px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ModalNav div:first-of-type{
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.ModalNav div:last-of-type{
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

JSX code for the component I am receiving props from

```
class App extends Component{
  state={
    showModal: false,
  }
  showModalHandler = ()=>{
    this.setState({showModal:!this.state.showModal})
  }
  render(){

  return (
    <div className="App">
      { this.state.showModal ?
        <Modal 
        show={this.state.showModal}
        clicked={this.showModalHandler}/> : null}

      { this.state.showModal ?
        <Backdrop 
        clicked={this.showModalHandler}/> : null}

        <Table clicked={this.showModalHandler}/>
    </div>
  );
}
}
export default App;
```

My goal is to get the modal to slide in but it just pops right in.

https://salesruby.netlify.app/ can be viewed here.

Comment: Can you describe what is not working and how it is not working in more detail.

Comment: You can also create a demo here: https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: I am trying to get the Modal to slide in from the left rather than just popping out. I seem to have written the CSS correctly and render them conditionally with React but it still does not slide in.

Comment: https://optimistic-babbage-d87485.netlify.app/
@Huangism That is a link to view the site. When you click on the hamburger menu, the modal just pops in. I am trying to make it slide in.

Comment: you could just create a separate component called modal and as soon as it loads the css transition will hit ?

Comment: @CyrusZei I did that it's not working.

Comment: Okej, let me try creating a sandbox

Comment: @CyrusZei I also updated the code. The link to view and the JSX code I am receiving props from

Comment: Looking at the link, it looks like the modal is being appended to the DOM and doesn't exist before. You can't use a transition on an element that doesn't exist.

Comment: @disinfor do you think its because of how I set the modal in the component I am getting the props from?

Comment: Yeah, I was also looking at the : null part of ternary - if you don't render the modal off to the left from the start then you can't slide it in later...

Comment: @MrRobboto what do you think it should be? I only started learning React a month ago.

Comment: @ChinomsoJohnson I'm not a react dev so don't know it that well, but when App returns what is to be rendered and placed in the DOM, you have it only render the Modal if it's in a show state (null if not). I'd think there you want to render the Modal no matter what, just in either a hidden or visible state. That way you can transition from the starting state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative answer that is more in line with OP's original approach of using CSS transition instead of animating. This also let's you slide the menu back in so it slides both ways.

OP's problem is returning null in the App component if the modal is in a hidden state (which it starts with). So react will not render the modal, until you change the isOpen flag to true - at that point it renders directly in the open state (popping in), and the CSS transition has no effect. Subsequently when you close the modal, it is removed from the DOM, again without time for a transition so it "pops out".

The solution below is to render the modal in its starting state, and use the IsOpen flag to toggle the state of the element, rather than pulling it in and out of the DOM.

Here is a modified sandbox from Cyrus' answer that shows this - isModalOpen flag is used by the Modal to toggle the "open" class. The rest is basically the same as what OP started with.
https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-architecture-9t50w?file=/src/Components/Modal/Modal.js

App (Notice Modal is always returned, no : null - and isModalOpen is bound)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Modal from "./Components/Modal/Modal";

const App = () => {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => setIsModalOpen(true)}>Open modal </button>
      <Modal isModalOpen={isModalOpen} closeModal={setIsModalOpen} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Modal (Notice className={isModalOpen ? "open" : ""} to toggle class)

```
import React from "react";
import "./modal.css";

const Modal = ({ closeModal, isModalOpen }) => {
  return (
    <div id="modal" className={isModalOpen ? "open" : ""}>
      Modal here <button onClick={() => closeModal(false)}> open modal</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

CSS (simple transform and transition effect)

```
#modal {
  background-color: #000000cc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
}

#modal.open {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

so I made this really fast. This is just a demo on how to make the animation slide in from left to right. If you look at the css you can see that I have left : -600px and that is the width of the modal. You can make it dynamic so that it will only take some % of the screen, but don't forget to add a max-width.

here is a link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-microservice-xrbiu?file=/src/Components/Modal/modal.css:0-344)

```
//app.js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Modal from "./Components/Modal/Modal";

const App = () => {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => setIsModalOpen(true)}>Open modal </button>
      {isModalOpen ? <Modal closeModal={setIsModalOpen} /> : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
//Modal.js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./modal.css";

const Modal = ({ closeModal }) => {
  return (
    <div id="modal">
      Modal here <button onClick={() => closeModal(false)}> open modal</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

```css
//modal.css
#modal {
  background-color: #000000cc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: top 2s;
  animation: slideIn 1s;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    left: -600px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 100px;
  }
}
```

Comment: This works. Thank you for taking the time to do this.